# How can I use pjsip in my app without redux?

Tags: react-native

I want to use pjsip (https://github.com/datso/react-native-pjsip) ,but I don`t wanna use redux.
Any help that could be given would be much appriciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

react-native-pjsip does not require redux. Even though the example app uses redux, all you really need are the API methods described in the readme for the module.

Comment: Are the API methods sufficient to use?

Comment: In theory they are. I had a much harder time figuring out the specifics of the SIP server I needed to connect to than than implementing the module methods. If you need special settings you should look into the source code of react-native-pjsip

Comment: Thanks alot ,I will do it